# Issue with regex for special characters in additional method jquery validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I have different rules for password validation. Most of them are working fine but the one for special characters is kind of tricky. The rule says: **The password must contain at least one special character (from a list of special characters)**. I created the additional method for jquery validate to handle this but for some reason characters outside of the list are treated as valid.

For example:

- 654321Ab/ is valid as / is an accepted special character
- 654321Ab/° must not be valid as ° is not a valid special character but now it is treated as correct

This is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o6L3s14c/

My script for the additional method:

```
$.validator.addMethod("pwcheckspechars", function (value) {
    return /[!@#$%^&*()_=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?+-]/.test(value)
}, "The password must contain at least one special character");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rule you report checks whether the string contains at least one of your special characters. Both the strings you mention are compliant with this rule (both contain `/`).

The fact that the second string contains an additional character which is not included in your rule does not change the validity of your test (`/` is still there).

You could add another validation method to check that your string contains only allowed characters, something along this line:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()_=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?+-]+$
```

which can be interpreted as:

> START (a-Z, A-Z, 0-9 or some special characters) one or more times
>   END

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/o6L3s14c/4/

Comment: Great. I didn't know I had to evaluate the allowed characters. :)

Comment: I found an issue. Try for example `654Ab%` in your jsfiddle. The error message says the password contains non-admitted characters. The thing is that the password does not contain invalid characters. I think it's because the {8,} at the end of the string. I tried removing it as I have the minlength and maxlength as rules too. However it does notwork. Any suggestion.

Comment: You are right. I changed the answer by modifying the quantifier ({8,} -> +). Now the regex checks that the string is at least one character long and that it contains only the specified characters.

Comment: I managed to handle this by moving the minlength and maxlength rules right after the required rule. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$.validator.addMethod("pwcheck", function(value) {

      return /^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()_=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?+-]+$/.test(value)
       && /[a-z]/.test(value) // has a lowercase letter
       && /\d/.test(value)//has a digit
       && /[!@#$%^&*()_=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?+-]/.test(value)// has a special character
      },"must consist  lowercase letter, number and special characters");
```